# WatchKit pull to refresh

Tags: ios, watchkit

Is it possible to implement a pull to refresh similar to the Watch email app? if not how else should I handle updating a `WKInterfaceTable`?

I don't really want the app to do an automatic refresh on load as this defeats the purpose of having a quick watch app.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Unfortunately it isn't possible at this time. `WKInterfaceTable`, like other WatchKit classes, doesn't offer much in the way of monitoring state. There's no way to monitor the scroll position.

Best you could do currently is add a button to your UI to initiate a refresh of the data or make use of the force touch menu.